# +1 and like buttons next to a question

Tags: feature-request, facebook, google-plus

I'd like +1 and like buttons for Google+ and Facebook below the sharing buttons next to each question. Sometimes, I'd just like to show I like it without sending a whole status update.

I e-mailed the team, but they tell me to ask the community before if it would like something like that too.

<--- The buttons would go here

Comment: The community is speaking loud and clear.

Comment: Aren't they there already? At least for some questions.

Comment: As the downvotes suggest, [social networking features are not appreciated by the community](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110958/166294)

Comment: He's requesting that he can like and +1, this is different than sharing.  Facebook (not sure about Google) doesn't require you to post to your wall when you like something.

Comment: Wow, that is **a lot** of downvotes. Wouldn't it be more productive to just remove the question?

Comment: @M.Babcock: No, we need to send a message so people stop suggesting crap like this. Stack Overflow is not a social networking site. We already have vote buttons.

Comment: @CodyGray - Fair enough. It's like watching a train wreck, I just can't seem to quit checking it.

Comment: @Cody This is meta, but "be nice" still applies; while it might seem like crap to you, someone who cares about the site took the time to formulate something that they believe would benefit the site.  You don't have to like it, but you need to respect the author, as they've done nothing warranting a response to themselves of that nature.

Comment: @casper: Uhh, I'm going to take that comment as being ironic, considering the things I've personally read you say to others. Besides, it wasn't "a response to themselves", it was a response to another user's comment regarding the deletion of this question. I don't think the question should be deleted because the answers and its reflection of a community consensus are useful. If the logic is that "someone who cares about the site took the time to formulate something that they believe would benefit the site", then you should upvote every proposal and stroke people's egos. You don't do that.

Comment: Do note that you already have a [favorite questions page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1267295/raptilicus?tab=favorites). Granted, the favorites are used for different purposes by different people, but you could use yours as a list of questions you liked. Funny enough, your little arrow is already pointing to the star that marks the question as a "favorite question".

Answer (score 18):

This is a bad idea because it unnecessarily duplicates and undermines existing functionality already built into the site (see: voting). The specific reasons why it is a bad idea can be broken down as follows:

- +1 and like buttons send mixed signals to users who are unsure whether to like, vote up, or do both.
- +1 and like undermine the current system of voting by fracturing its functionality across multiple platforms.
- The system for tracking trending / popular questions becomes fractured.

The ability to socially share links to a question is far more useful because it doesn't detract from the voting system and simultaneously promotes site activity through the social sharing of questions.